# Run script using Browserify without build process first

Tags: javascript, requirejs, dependency-management, browserify

I read through many articles on `Browserify` like http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2013/11/backbone-browserify/ and there is always a step such as below:

```
$ browserify app/app.js | uglifyjs > app/bundle.js
```

This seems to be done **before** you run the script in the browser to see how it works. Is there a way **NOT** having to do **build** each time I change code? Something similar to `define()` function in `requirejs`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I originally said you can't do this for the reasons below, but I want to add that where there is a will there is a way. I'm sure given enough time and effort, you (or someone) could (and probably will) come up with a way to accomplish this task - but as of right now (12/12/13), I don't know if there's any out of the box tools that will facilitate it.

1. browserify "modules" are written using the same concept as node.js modules. You write your code, and export any public methods/properties/etc via a `module.exports` object. Javascript in the browser doesn't support this sort of thing natively. There are some boilerplate templates (some info [here](https://github.com/umdjs/umd)) to help facilitate this in the browser, and they can be compatible with browserify, but...
2. When you browserify your code, the browserify script analyzes your syntax and finds the modules that it has to make available via the `require` method. This require method gets defined right in your bundle.js that you export, along with all the code for all the dependencies that your module needs. This allows the require method that browserify defines to work synchronously, returning a reference to the module that you requested immediately without waiting for any kind of web response (like, loading a js script).

Require.js works fundamentally differently than browserify. Require.js defines your packages using the `define` syntax you referenced, and exposes a `require` method which you use to tell Require.js which modules your code depends on. Require.js then, in turn, looks up the dependencies you require and if it hasn't loaded them for another module yet, generates a new script tag and forces your browser to load that module, waiting to execute your code until that is complete. This is an asynchronous process, which means, the javascript engine continues to process instructions while it waits for the new script to download, parse, and execute. Require.js wraps all of this up in some callbacks, so it can wait until all your dependencies are satisfied, before allowing your defined code to execute (which is why you pass functions to `require` and `define`, so require.js can execute them when it's ready).

The biggest reason to not want to bundle every time you make a change in development, is just for speed of iteration. Some things you can do (with browserify) to improve performance (that is, speed of bundling) are:

- Don't uglify your code during development. You can just bundle it using browserify (make sure you use `-d`, for sourcemaps) without uglifying/minifying it, that should speed up the bundle performance a bit (for larger projects, anyway).
- Split up your modules a little bit. Modules that don't have direct dependencies with one another don't have to be built at the same time. You can include different modules in your application using multiple script tags, or you can concatenate browserify bundles files together. You could absolutely set up some grunt tasks to watch your code for changes, and only compile the modules which contained the code change. This will cut out a lot of wasted cpu cycles, since browserify won't have to parse and transform multiple modules, just the ones that changed. From there you can re-concatenate into one big bundle, or just stick with the multiple bundle includes on the page.

Comment: Thank you for the detail explanation sir. `-d` and `grunt watch` is a good one to speed things up.

Comment: the `-d` option won't necessarily speed up compilation, but it will probably speed up debugging in the browser, since you'll have sourcemaps (:

Comment: or u can simply use requirejs.

Answer (score 11):

It's 2015 now and there's a library for this, it's called [drq](https://github.com/manvalls/drq). It uses internally sync xhr requests, so it's only well suited for development purposes. You just have to include it:

```
<script src="drq.js"></script>
```

And then, you can do your require calls in any script of the page:

```
<script>

var myModule = require('my-module'),
    myClass = require('./classes/my-class.js');

// etc.

</script>
```

It will look for node modules up to your web root, so be sure to `npm install` them at a directory not upper than it. Also, please take a look at the [GitHub page](https://github.com/manvalls/drq) where you can find some tips to increase performance.

Again, please remember that bundles are the optimal solution for production.

Comment: Thanks for the link to drq! I can't wait to check this out. I inevitably run into caching problems with Browserify, or the source map in the chrome debugger gets out of sync with the page, then even when it works there's a couple second delay on bigger projects between saving and when gulp watch finishes building. I'm hoping using drq to avoid building a single bundle file in development fixes these issues without having to switch to Requirejs.